# Get Current Date time of the server on which my website is hosted

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Am working on a functionality that involves a few timing based tasks.I need to retrieve current EST time to continue with my functionality.I do not need the  system time since it may be different for each users.Is it possible using javascript or c# to get Eastern Standard Time from another time server or get time from my hosted server so that i can convert it to Eastern Standard Time .

am currently using this line of code to get eastern standard time but this is not i wanted since it is based on system time.

```
 DateTime eastern = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "Eastern Standard Time");
```

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow` is the UTC time: it's independent of the actual timezone your server is in. `DateTime.Now` is the "local time" of your server (which might be what you're looking for).

Comment: @zneak DateTime.UtcNow is it dependent on our current system time ???

Comment: It returns the time on your server adjusted to the UTC timezone. So if you're in the EST time zone and your server's clock tells it's 3 AM, `UtcNow` will return 8 AM. (Since it relies on your server's clock, make sure that it's configured with the correct date, time and timezone.)

Comment: @karthi: You need to distinguish between the system *time* and the system *time zone*. Yes, the code you've given depends on the system time - but it *doesn't* depend on the system time zone.

Comment: @JonSkeet how can i get Eastern standard time which is not depended on our system time..I mean two users can have different time on your system ..but i need process them based on eastern standard time which should be be same for both .Please help

Comment: @karthi: No, users *won't* have different times on the system. By "system time" I mean the internal clock on the server. That *doesn't* depend on the user. How it's converted to a local time depends on the time zone, but you're specifying that already. The code you've given will already give Eastern time (standard or daylight, depending on where DST is in effect).

Comment: @karthi, will "Feb 12, 3405 3PM EST" work for your "not depended on our system time"? What is **your** definition of "system time"?

Comment: @JonSkeet so do you  mean this code is not effected even if the client machine has different time?Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: "Eastern Standard Time" is ambiguous, there are three different time zones that use that name (and no standard to define them). Much better to use UTC and adjust using the offset in hours or minutes, whatever suits.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov by system time i meant Client machine time

Comment: The code you've shown runs on server and uses server's time(assuming you provided correct ASP.Net tag). There is actually no easy way for it to use client machine's time (assuming "client machine"== machine where browser runs) on a server.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code looks correct - it returns current time in EST time zone.

There are potentially 4 different values for "now" in your case and I think you have right one:

- UTC "now" - now in UTC time zone. - the same value irrespective of location/locale/anything.
- Time in server local time zone (i.e. PST)  - depends on server configuration
- Time in browser's user time zone (i.e. India's half-an-hour timezone) - varies per user.
- Time in EST.- the same value irrespective of location/locale/anything.

It is safe to convert UTC to known time zone as you did.

If you are not satisfied with precision/correctness of time on particular machine you can obtain time from a server that supports [Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol), but synchroniztion of clocks between machines is non-trivial task, so think first if it what you need.